# How to create automatic Item Divider for React Native FlatLists?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a list of events that I am rendering in a FlatList. I would like there to be a divider whenever the event is on a different date - aka when {item.eventID.eventDate} for a given item is different to the one before it (I already know how to call the sever to return the dates in order).

Is there a way to autogenerate these dividers?

Here is my function for each item of the FlatList:

```
function Item({ item }) {
  return (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.eventID.eventDate}</Text>
        <Text>{item.eventID.artistName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.ticketID}</Text>
      </View>
  );
}
```

And here is my class component for the page:

```
export default class MyEventsScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    tickets: [],
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fullticket/", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          tickets: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
            <FlatList
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              data={this.state.tickets}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.ticketID}
            />          
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom function to render divider when the date value is changed.

The new Item function and renderDivider:

```
let prevDate = ""
function renderDivider(date) {
  if(prevDate === "" || date !== prevDate) {
    prevDate = date //initialize prevDate
    return <Text style={styles.divider}>----{date}---</Text>
  }
}
function Item({ item }) {
  return (
      <View>
        {renderDivider(item.eventID.eventDate)}
        <Text>{item.eventID.artistName}</Text>

      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  divider: {
    marginVertical: 15,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
  }
});
```